# Pycharm Unicode Produces Box with Question Mark

Tags: pycharm, python-unicode

I'm running Pycharm on a Mac Mini and another instance of Pycharm on a MacBook Air.  Unicode for superscript 2 (\u2072) works on Pycharm on the Mini but not on Pycharm on the MacBook Air.  On the MBA it produces a question mark box in my GUI and a box with diagonal line through it when I paste the same line of code in the Console.

Played "one of these things is not like the other" but no success.

- MacOS Sonoma on both. Both are Mac silicon (M2).
- Python 3.12 interpreter on both.
- Same editor Font on both.
- Checked the installed Packages and nothing stands out to me.

Any ideas?  Thanks :)

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SHELL` in each system? You can also try `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: echo $SHELL gives /bin/zsh on both machines.  I managed to get it to work with chr() instead:  ms2_label = tb.Label(master=frame3, text="m/s" + chr(0x00b2)") for what it's worth.  Still curious why the unicode fails on the MBA when they're so similarly configured.

Comment: AFAIK, - `⁲` (U+2072,  *Undefined*)
- `²` (U+00B2,  *Superscript Two*) in the latest Unicode (version 15)…

Comment: That also worked: text="m/s\u00b2: " instead of the previously used \u2072.  I went to add Unicode V15 to my bookmarks for future reference and it says "2072-->reserved 00B2 superscript 2" so that must have been the confusion / reason I used \u2072 to start.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with: text="m/s\u00b2: " instead of the previously used “m/s\u2072”.

I went to add Unicode V15 to my bookmarks for future reference and it says "2072-->reserved 00B2 superscript 2" so that must have been the confusion / reason I used \u2072 to start.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).